# Amazon CloudFront: How to get monthly cost breakdown per distribution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'd like to manage the hosting for multiple clients, using my own Amazon CloudFront account. Each client has its own CloudFront distribution. But the AWS monthly bill doesn't break down by distribution. How can I find out what the cost was for each distribution?

Ideally, the solution will also work for S3. With S3, I can use "cost allocation tags" for this purpose I believe, but those don't seem to apply to CloudFront. Is there a single solution or best practice I can use that will work with both, to learn the cost incurred for a client across CloudFront and S3?

If the only solution is to create a separate AWS account per client, what's the best practice for doing that? Since I'm paying all the bills on behalf of these multiple clients, I'd like to keep the accounting and account management simple on my side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last field of the `Detailed billing report` is ResourceId, which appears to contain the distribution ID or alias for the distribution. I've seen both "ID" and "alias" listed for the same distribution, so I don't know why.

Comment: The only way to get this is to go to Preferences --> Receiving Billing Reports and enter an S3 bucket; wait until next month because reports for months prior to this configuration can't be generated; and then go to Bills --> Download CSV?

Comment: It's not retroactive. I think it will start within a day of enabling, though, as the billing segments are hourly.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to download the .csv, in the "New format". There are rows for CloudFront operations, with costs, but no ResourceId column. Any idea what I'm missing? I tried "Old format" but it just takes me to the Billing & Cost Management Dashboard, nothing is downloaded – it seems like that doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I had this issue as well—make sure you're opening the CSV file that includes resources AND tags. The regular cost allocation report won't include the `ResourceID` column. These are compressed and will look something like `xxxxx-aws-billing-detailed-line-items-with-resources-and-tags-2015-06.csv.zip`

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! For me it's all ID #'s for the CloudFront distro which is a drag but I guess that's the best there is. If anyone knows how to get that to reliably be a human readable name that would be great. 

Also am I crazy to be doing this under one account?

Comment: cloudfront's `list-distributions` can convert from the ID to something you prefer- such as a cname, for instance.